# UWP C# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when saving XML file

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to write some data to an already existing XML file as you can see below:

I already tried to give everyone full permission. This hasn't worked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhG1R.jpg

Xml file I am trying to write to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
<story>
<content>
Example story 12345678
</content>
<score>
10
</score>
</story>
</list>
```

My code for updating the XML file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(@"Scorelist.xml");
XmlNode mnodeMain = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Story", null);

XmlNode nodeStory = doc.CreateElement("Content");
nodeStory.InnerText = txt_verhaaldisplay.Text;

XmlNode nodeScore = doc.CreateElement("Score");
nodeScore.InnerText = txt_ratinginput.Text;

mnodeMain.AppendChild(nodeStory);
mnodeMain.AppendChild(nodeScore);

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(mnodeMain);

doc.Save(@"Scorelist.xml"); <--- This is where I am getting an error
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path'D:\Programs\Story Generator\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Scorelist.xml' is denied.'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I gave the full permission to the file, what could it be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP you cannot write to the app's installation folder. This is to ensure the app folder's integrity and to allow incremental updates for the app.

To solve this, copy the file to your local appdata folder and then you can update it there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Even when I transferred the XML file to my local appdata folder, and changed the paths in the code, I still got the same error. The only difference was that instead of getting the error at "doc.save" I instead already got the error at "doc.load".

I think I might have misunderstood the instructions.

Comment: Where exactly did you copy it? It needs go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder

This is your app-specific local folder (not your general purpose app data folder).

Comment: Oh, woops. Sorry, I misunderstood. I actually thought you meant the general purpose app data folder, my mistake.

https://imgur.com/a/uj8wqOY

This is where my XML file is located as of right now. I am not sure where my local app data is and how to acces it through my program. Sorry for the beginner mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to know where the folder is located. Your app can copy the file there by using this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder

Use the same API later to read from and write to the file.

Comment: Alright, sorry for misunderstanding. I believe I correctly added the API and I changed the path to : ms-appx:///ScoreList.xml Instead, now I am getting a new error System.NotSupportedException: 'The URI prefix is not recognized.'

I think I might have done something wrong again. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correction: I saw that I entered the wrong path so I changed it to ms-appdata:///local/ScoreList.xml still getting the same error though. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you can get the path of your local appdata folder by `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` and check if your xml file is in it. If it has existed, you can use `string XMLFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ScoreList.xml");` to get  your xml file path, then using `doc.Load(XMLFilePath); doc.Save(XMLFilePath);` to load and save it.